# Ajax button no longer updates in Rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I implemented a "follow" feature from Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial. It worked fine for months but now all of a sudden the button no longer updates once it quits. I don't get any Javascript errors, nor do I get any errors in the Rails console. Clicking on the button will successfully create/destroy the "relationship". I only get an error in the Rails console when I try to click on the button again because it's trying to redo the transaction.

I do precompile my assets but this was never a problem. I had always precompiled my assets and pushed the app to Heroku and the button worked fine. The only change I implemented recently was the addition of the simple_form and haml-rails gems in order to get the mailboxer gem working right. I'm not sure if they are related but I figured that may help debug.

How did this break and how can I fix it? THANKS!

Relevant code:

Controller:

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    current_user.follow!(@user)
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

follow form

```
<% unless current_user == @user %>
  <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
    <%= render 'unfollow' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'follow' %>
  <% end %>
```

follow

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @user.id),
             remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
<%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-primary btn-small" %>
<% end %>
```

unfollow

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.find_by_followed_id(@user),
             html: { method: :delete },
             remote: true) do |f| %>
<%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn btn-primary btn-small" %>
<% end %>
```

create.js.erb

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow')) %>")
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>')
```

destroy.js.erb

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/follow')) %>")
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>')
```

application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.

//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery.tokeninput
//= require_tree .
```

I used to have `//= require jquery_ujs` in the application.js but I had to remove it because clicking on the Follow button would cause the click to occur twice. Removing that line solved that problem, but the Ajax just doesn't seem to be updating the button anymore and I can't figure out why.

**EDIT:**

Rails console does show that the request is being received. I can even refresh the page and then the button will update:

```
Started DELETE "/relationships/32" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-13 21:35:37 -0500
Processing by RelationshipsController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"---edited---", "commit"=>"Unfollow", "id"=>"32"}
  Relationship Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "relationships".* FROM "relationships" WHERE "relationships"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "32"]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Relationship Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "relationships".* FROM "relationships" WHERE "relationships"."follower_id" = 1 AND "relationships"."followed_id" = 2 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "relationships" WHERE "relationships"."id" = $1  [["id", 32]]
   (1.5ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered users/_follow.html.erb (2.5ms)
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "relationships" ON "users"."id" = "relationships"."follower_id" WHERE "relationships"."followed_id" = 2
  Rendered relationships/destroy.js.erb (6.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 17.4ms (Views: 8.0ms | ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)
```

The Javascript console doesn't show any errors at all in Chrome.

**EDIT 2**
My network tab:

[image: Network tab in Chrome Javascript console]

Comment: Browser and server console are helpful when troubleshooting AJAX interactions: 1. is request being sent by browser? 2. is server receiving it? 3. is Rails filtering paramaters?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Edited question. Rails console shows that the request is being completed. It even states "rendered relationships/create.js.erb". No errors are found in the Javascript console in Chrome

Comment: Does adding an `alert("test")` in the create.js.erb pop up?

Comment: Yes, the alert box does pop up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I was missing the `<div id="follow_form">` on the follow form:

```
<% unless current_user == @user %>
 <div id="follow_form">
  <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
    <%= render 'unfollow' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'follow' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If your `create.js.erb` works (from your alert), the problem is going to be with the rendering of your JS

This is your current `create.js.erb`:

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow')) %>")
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>')
```

1. Does `#follow_form` still exist?
2. Can you call `users/unfollow`?
3. Does `#followers` exist?

I think it's going to be a problem in your `create.js.erb`. You can check this by clicking on `right-click` -> `inspect element` -> `network` -> `request you just sent` -- if there's an error, it will be red

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just checked the network tab in the console and it shows that the relationship POST has a status of "OK", but the button just doesn't change. No javascript errors as far as I can tell. I do have a _follow_form.html.erb, but I don't see a followers.html.erb . Could that be the problem? Looking at Michael Hartl's source code he doesn't have it either

Comment: It could be! do you have anything in your `preview` sub-tab?

Comment: Doesn't look like it, although I may not be looking in the right place. I don't see an actual tab, nor do I see a Preview subtab inside the Network tab. Maybe I'm missing a .js file or they are misplaced? I have them in the same place as M Hartl: the create and destroy .js.erb files are in the views/relationships folder. I don't have anything like that in my actualy javascripts folder. As far as I can tell I completely match what Michael Hartl has in his source code

Comment: Hmm okay - the best thing would be if you could take a screenshot of your `network` tab? It will help me see what's actually going on :)

Comment: Updated the question with a screenshot. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

in Js console look up the **Network** tag and check the **preview** of ajax request to verify what  respond the server, maybe  the ids or class names are different